# Converting lists whose elements' types are paramertized their type-encoded indexes

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-safety, gadt, successor-arithmetics

I'm trying to implement a type-safe [binomial heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap). For this, I have two data types whose element types are parametrized by their type-encoded indexes:

```
data Zero
data Succ a = Succ

{-| A GADT representation of lists with type-encoded length.
    Unlike the most common implementation, the type paramater
    for values is of kind * -> *. Each element type is
    parametrized by its index (counting from the end of the vector),
    so the type-encoded numbers decrease from start to end.
-}
data Vec n a where
    Nil  ::                   Vec Zero a
    Cons :: a n -> Vec n a -> Vec (Succ n) a

{-| A GADT representation of lists whose values are of kind
    * -> *. Each element type is parametrized by its by its
    index (counting from the start of the vector), so the
    type-encoded numbers increase from start to end.
    Unlike Vec the type-encode number here doesn't represent
    the length, it can be arbitrary (just increasing).
-}
data RVec n a where
    RNil  ::                           RVec n a
    RCons :: a n -> RVec (Succ n) a -> RVec n a
```

`Vec` encodes values with decreasing number parameter, where the last element is always parametrized by `Zero`. `RVec` encodes values with increasing number parameter with no other restriction (this is why `RNil` can produce `RVec` of any number).

This allows me (for example) to have a list of trees with increasing/decreasing heights, checked by the type system. After implementing a large part of my project, I realized I need a seemingly simple function, which I wasn't able to implement:

```
vreverse :: Vec n a -> RVec Zero a
```

It should simply reverse the order of the given list. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to first implement `vreverse' :: Vec n a -> RVec m a`, starting the `RVec` from an arbitrary point.  I think you can define that recursively, and then you can specialize that to the case of `RVec Zero a`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I thought that too at first. But it's not that easy. Because the elements have encoded their indexes in their types, it's not possible to implement `Vec n a -> RVec m a`. Since the last element of `Vec n a` is of type `a Zero`, the result _must_ be `RVec Zero a` so that its first element is of type `a Zero` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your reference, the [third article of Issue 16 of the Monad.Reader](http://themonadreader.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/issue-16/)...which, um, I wrote...discusses type-safe binomial heaps in Haskell, and how to implement them correctly.

Comment: A very nice article. Your approach is better that it doesn't need GADTs, which makes things simpler. I'll try to complete my variant and then compare them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found an answer:

```
vreverse :: Vec n a -> RVec Zero a
vreverse v = f1 v RNil
  where
    f1 :: Vec n a -> (RVec n a -> RVec Zero a)
    f1 Nil = id
    f1 (Cons x xs) = f1 xs . RCons x
```